# Contain an iframe with overflow:hidden (in Safari)

Tags: css, iframe

I am using a third-party iframe to serve up certain content, and I have this iframe wrapped in a containing div with a `border-radius` and `overflow: hidden`. However, the content of the iframe seems to disregard both of these.

```
.iframe-container {
  border: 8px solid red;
  border-radius: 40px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

<div class="iframe-container">
  <iframe... />
</div>
```

[image: ive exaggerated the issue to better show]

Anyone have any suggestions?

UPDATE
This issue seems to be limited to Safari.

Comment: In Chrome Working F9

Comment: Ah! you're right, this does work in Chrome for me as well. Perhaps this issue is limited to Safari?

Comment: Why did someone downvote this and not say why?

Comment: add the vendor prefixes to border-radius may solve the problem

Comment: @samehanwar thanks, but i tried that and still no dice for Safari...

Comment: try to use percentage value rather than pixels, it might help

Comment: sorry @samehanwar that didn't work either.

Answer (score 1):

i dont see any html code for the image and the iframe, so i think you need to give your image a class then add `border-radius: 40px;` to that image class. 
They will match perfect.

i hope that will help you.

Comment: There is no image, the image above is injected into the iframe. And giving a border-radius directly on the iframe doesn't have any affect in Safari.

Comment: `<img style="border-radius: 40px; " src="image.png"  />` Lets say that is the link of your injected image. just add a style with the border radius. I think it will work for you

Comment: ah, I now understand what you mean. However, this iframe uses a divs with a background-image rather than actually injecting an image object. Also, I wasn't aware that you could affect the styling of the contents of an iframe.

Comment: can you post the entire code such that i can see exactly what you mean. Am just guessing the solution. or try removing the `overflow: hidden;`

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `border-radius` and `overflow` from the parent div

Then add the `border-radius` property to `iframe` instead